# ByteBuddy Method Interceptor With @AllArguments Doesn't Seem To Work

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am exploring ByteBuddy for a project of mine. I am trying to intercept an annotated method as:

```
import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy.Default;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;

public class Fibonacci {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Fibonacci fibonacci =
        new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Fibonacci.class)
            .method(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(PreCondition.class))
            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new FiboAgent()))
            .make()
            .load(Fibonacci.class.getClassLoader(), Default.WRAPPER)
            .getLoaded()
            .newInstance();
    fibonacci.printFibo(5);
  }

  @PreCondition(expression = "n > 5")
  public void printFibo(Integer i) {
    System.out.println("Here");
  }
}
```

FiboAgent.java:

```
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.AllArguments;

public class FiboAgent {
  public void intercept(@AllArguments Object[] args) {
    System.out.println("Intercepted");
  }
}
```

I am not able to figure out why this doesn't work.

ByteBuddy version: 1.10.19

Comment: I do not really understand why so many developers believe that it is better to post an incoherent set of code snippets which nobody can copy, compile and just run in order to reproduce the problem, but make it more difficult to find help, instead of just posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which would yield immediate answers without burdening each potential volunteer to try and guess what the real code looks like and try to fill in the missing parts of a jigsaw puzzle before actually being able to answer an otherwise simple question. Brevity over reproducibility - why?

Comment: I apologise. This was a relatively simple piece of code (and I felt like I was making a stupid mistake) so I didn't really post the entire thing. I have update the question to have a MCVE.

Comment: There is no piece of code too simple to make a mistake. This is human rather than stupid. See how your full classes with imports made it easy for Rafael to answer your question? (I would have, but just woke up in my current time zone.) Now it is also clear that your formerly 3 code snippets actually just belong to 2 classes, which is not crucial here but can well be in other situations. The annotation's package name was the important information. To be fair, you mentioned it before, but not as part of the code but somewhere after the code in a sentence, which was hard to notice.

Comment: I always feel a bit uneasy when lecturing people here about how to ask questions, afraid they could take it personally. But I do it anyway because I know that if they follow the advice, I will have helped them to help themselves, because if it is easy to reproduce a problem it is much more likely to solve it than if a helper has to start speculating and making (more or less) educated guesses. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately simple error to make. There is a difference between *Advice* and *MethodDelegation*. Method delegation is more powerful but also more intrusive on a byte code level what makes it less attractive to Java agents which often cannot add members. To make it simpler to switch between the two, the annotations are aligned since advice covers a subset of the delegation functionality. If you replace:

```
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.AllArguments;
```

with

```
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.AllArguments;
```

everything should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Rafael for the answer, this was the mistake I was making. Looks like need to read the docs a bit more thoroughly.